# c# What loop to use

Tags: c#, loops

Ok so my question is this, I currently have 3 possible answers: yes, no, and everything else. I want my program to write "Pardon me?" until I answer yes or no... I'm new to using c# and still learning so please as simple as possible. Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Pitalica
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kvisko");
        Console.WriteLine("\"Hello Traveller!!\" says a man. \"What's your name?\"");
        string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\"Hi " + playerName + ", welcome to the beautiful city of Osijek!\nI would like to give you a tour of our little town, but I don't have time to do so right now.\nI need to go to class.\"");
        Console.WriteLine("He looks at you with your backpack on your back.\"But I could show you later if you're up to?\"");
        string answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer1 == "yes")

            Console.WriteLine("\"We have a deal, " + playerName + "!\"");
        else if (answer1 == "no")

            Console.WriteLine("\"Your loss," + playerName + "...\"");
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pardon me?");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After some time...");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `After some time...` an answer to your question.

Comment: since I'm still learning : After some time... should be only if persons answers yes... if they answer no I just want it to say your loss and close the program

Answer (score 7):

Technically, you can implement *any* loop, but I suggest `while`

```
 ...
 string answer1 = Console.ReadLine();

 while (answer1 != "yes" && answer1 != "no") {
   Console.WriteLine("Pardon me?");
   answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
 }
 ...
```

Just keep asking *while* `answer1` is not a correct one.

**Edit:** As Hogan suggested in the comment, we should be *nice* to user: let he/she enter YES/no in any register with leading and trailing white spaces:

```
 ...
 // with Trim() and ToUpper() all "Yes", "   yes", "YES  " are OK
 string answer1 = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();

 while (answer1 != "YES" && answer1 != "NO") {
   Console.WriteLine("Pardon me?");

   answer1 = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();
 }
 ...
```

**Edit 2**: to exit the program (see an additional question in the comments), just *return* from the `Main`:

```
 ...
 if (answer1 == "NO") {
   Console.WriteLine("Your loss"); 

   return; // return from Main will exit the program
 }
```

Comment: maybe use `answer1.ToUpper().Trim()` just to make it easier on the user

Comment: @Hogan: Thank you for the suggestion! - the software should be nice to user.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.. 
One more question guys... If they answer no how do I stop the program...
Cause now it only continue with the story...

Comment: @Osti991: if you want to break program's execution all you have to do is to *return* (see my edit, please)